# "Il est un [X]" supplanté par "c'est un [X]"

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, démonstratifs

En traduisant du texte de l'anglais au français, j'ai remarqué le phénomène suivant qui ne m'avait jamais « choqué » jusqu'ici :

> He is a man. => C'est un homme.
>
> He is a genius. => C'est un génie.

On pourrait littéralement traduire de la façon suivante :

> He is a man. => Il est un homme.
>
> He is a genius. => Il est un génie.

La construction « Il est un homme » me semble grammaticalement correcte et plus précise car renvoyant directement au sujet « il », mais pourtant sonne bizarre, voire faux à l'oreille comparée à « C'est un homme ».

Par ailleurs, si j'avais utilisé un nom comme sujet, par exemple « Jean est un génie », ça sonne cette fois-ci tout à fait correct.

Existe t-il une raison historique au fait que la construction « Il/Elle est un(e) [X] » ne soit pas usitée ?

Comment: Petite remarque destinée à ceux qui arriveraient là pour un autre motif : "Il est un [X]" est aussi une tournure littéraire qui signifie "Il existe un [X]". Par exemple, "Il est un pays où il ne pleut jamais." C'est probablement de là que vient l'expression : "Il était une fois [...]".

Comment: On peut aussi noter que ceci ne s'applique que lorsque l'on a un article après le verbe. « Il est médecin » est tout à fait correct, ainsi qu'« elle est géniale » (mais on a là un adjectif au lieu d'un nom).

Answer (score 4):

Je crois que ce qui accroche au niveau du sens de l'expression *il est un [X]* en particulier, c'est qu'elle a pris le sens de *il y a un* (par exemple`: *il était un petit navire*), mais lié à un registre particulièrement formel.

Cette association avec *il y a* est suffisamment forte pour faire que si on tente d'employer *il est un* en utilisant *il* comme un pronom personnel plutôt qu'impersonnel (ce qu'il est dans une formule comme *Il est un principe bien établi que ...*), on aboutit essentiellement à ce que les anglophones appellent une *[garden path sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_path_sentence)*, une phrase dont la syntaxe doit être réanalysée en cours de route, ce qui cause un soubresaut dans la communication qu'on peut assimiler à une faute de grammaire.

Answer (score 2):

La construction "Il est un homme" est grammaticalement correcte mais pose un problème sémantique. C'est l'emploi du sujet "il" et de l'article "un" qui pose problème.

"Il" est un pronom défini. 
"Ce / c'" correspond à "cette personne" a un sens indéfini.

De même : "un" est un article indéfini contrairement à "le"

Dans la phrase "Il est l'homme", le sens accroche car le complément d'objet de la phrase, devant apporter une précision, est plus général que le sujet déjà évoqué.

Par opposition dans la locution "C'est un homme", on retrouve deux ensembles ayant la même précision.

Comment: Bonne explication. Par contre ça ne me semble pas expliquer pourquoi "Jean est un homme" sonne bien ... ?

Comment: Mauvaise explication. *Il est Jean* ne fonctionne pas non plus.

Comment: Il devrait y avoir un rapport avec le fait que ce *ce* ne peut être le sujet que de *être*. C'est une situation spécifique pour cette construction qui ne se produit pas avec d'autres verbes...

Comment: @fatalize Jean est un homme sonne effectivement bien, mais dans ce cas "un homme" ajoute une information à ce qu'est Jean. Il y aurait une différence sémantique entre dire : Jean est un homme, on le spécifie comme "humanoide", voire "humanoide male" selon le contexte, mais on pourrait aussi dire "Jean est l'homme" qui sous entend soit "l'homme de la situation", soit "l'homme" parmi les femmes. Dans les deux cas, le COD apporte une précision sur le sujet.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez : Il est Jean ne fonctionne pas car c'est grammaticalement bancal. "Il" est un pronom, qui représente "Jean". La phrase "Jean est Jean" n'a donc pas de sens. par contre on pourrait très bien dire "Jean est Grégoire", en définissant que les deux personnes ne font q'une.

Comment: In paragraph 2 you say:«'Il’ est un article défini».Are you using «article» here in a general (non-grammatical) way to mean “objet”?
Also (& this probably comes from either my confusion about what you mean by “article” or from my mistranslation of “accrocher”) in paragraph 4 you say that the sense of "Il est l'homme" “accoroche”/?clashes? more than "C'est un homme", but I don’t see why “Il” used with “le” (definite “article”+definite article=similar precision/balance) is less similarly precise/balanced than using “ce/c’” with “un”(indefinite sense+indefinite article=similar precision/balance).

Comment: @PapaPoule, I'll try to answer you in english, even if I'm risking to be unclear. In this case just tell me, I won't hold it against you ;)
First of all, I've edited my message because I meant 'Il est un pronom défini" (not an article). Grammatically speaking I'm opposing "Il" (defined) to "On or Ce, C'" (undefined pronoun).
In paragraph 4, yes I'm meaning that both parts of the sentence clash with each other. If I'm trying to translate "Il est l'homme", I would say something like "He is this man".

Comment: @CitronEvanescent "Il est Roméo dans la pièce de Cocteau""Il est l'homme qui a vu l'homme" dans le texte de Prévert monté en spectacle, fonctionnent aussi. C'est en effet un problème sémantique, il y a donc quelque chose à compléter dans votre réponse.

Comment: @cl-r Effectivement, on peut toujours trouver un sens particulier. La question était selon moi posée dans le cas général. Même la "Il est l'homme" pourrait être juste selon le contexte : Imaginons que l'on parle d'un homme qu'on aurait vu faire quelque chose d'extraordinaire et que dans un discours on pointe quelqu'un "Il est l'homme", sous entendu "il est l'homme [dont on parle]" devient juste. 

Ce n'est pas un problème de grammaire de sémantique. 

Dans le  cas du 'il est l'homme qui a vu l'homme' la subordonnée apporte une précision.

Answer (score 0):

Si tu parles anglais, regarde ce [lien](http://french.about.com/library/weekly/aa032500.htm).

Ça explique la différence entre les deux. Je n'ai pas trouvé de site en français qui explique la différence.

Comment: Ma question n'est pas de savoir quelle différence il y a entre "il est" et "c'est" ni dans quelle situation employer l'un ou l'autre, mais de savoir pourquoi "il est un ..." n'est pas employée alors que la construction semble grammaticalement correcte.

Comment: Si tu avais regardé le lien, tu aurais compris qu'il n'est pas utilisé car **c'est** est utilisé avant les adjectifs. Tu peux dire "il est un homme" mais ça sonne mal.

Comment: La question est justement de savoir pourquoi "il est un homme" sonne mal. La réponse est évidemment parce que cette construction n'est pas utilisée et donc choque l'oreille, mais y a t-il une raison à cette non-utilisation ?