# Avoiding "il est un" and "elle est une"

Tags: pronoms

I've noticed that in my French practice I never say "il est un" or "elle est une". I would always say either "il/elle est" or "c'est" or "c'est un/une".

So far this does not seem to have caused me to have any problems.

Are there any times when I should be saying "il est un" or "elle est une"?

Comment: Voir aussi : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6317/what-is-the-difference-between-cest-and-il-est/37726#37726

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nowadays, using *il est un* / *elle est une* is typical from non native French speakers.

This form is not a grammatical mistake. It sounds archaic but might still be used in formal or literary contexts with the meaning "there is a". It is never required.

See this reply to a question very similar to yours and that explains why *c'est un(e)* took the lead: https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14729/1109

> Are there any times when I should be saying "il est un" or "elle est une"?

Almost: *Il est une heure* ;-)

Answer (score 3):

No, it means the same. My theory for that is simple, as « *C'est un/une* »  or « *Il/elle est* » is shorter to say, it gets adopted and used a lot more in verbal's form.