# Les noms sans forme féminine, comment les utiliser ？

Tags: grammaire, genre, noms

Bonjour à tous!

Cette question me préoccupe depuis longtemps.

D'après mon livre du grammaire, les noms qui désignent des fonctions et profession comme: professeur/médecin/chef/magistrat/amateur... n'ont que la forme masculine. Donc pour cette phrase "Il est un bon professeur/médecin/magistrat/chef/amateur" Comment le dire par le sujet "elle"? Elle est une bonne chef, ou elle est un bon médecin? Je dois utiliser quel article ici, une ou un?
Merci bcp!

Comment: Pour une première approche : https://french.stackexchange.com/q/2005/635

Comment: Avec *elle*, ni *un* ni *une*: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/38303/avoiding-il-est-un-and-elle-est-une

Comment: Et aussi *sage-femme* https://french.stackexchange.com/q/42701/1893

Answer (score 10):

Ça dépend.

La langue française est en cours d'évolution. Les noms de professions traditionnellement masculins sont de plus en plus féminisés. Mais la manière de féminiser dépend des mots, et certains évoluent plus que d'autres. De plus, tout le monde n'applique pas les mêmes règles. Les usages sont différents dans les différents pays francophones ; ma réponse concerne la France.

Le mot *amateur* a un féminin parfaitement accepté *amatrice*. Même [Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/amatrice) (qui date du milieu du 19<sup>e</sup> siècle et était conservateur) l'accepte.

> C'est un bon amateur.
> C'est une bonne amatrice.

(Note qu'on dit « c'est … » et pas « il/elle est … » lorsque le complément est un nom.)

Pour *[professeur](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/professeur)*, on dit presque toujours « une professeur » au féminin. Les féminins « une [professeure](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/professeure) » et « une [professeuse](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/professeuse) » existent aussi mais sont très peu utilisés. Même lorsqu'on garde l'orthographe *professeur* au féminin, le nom s'accorde au féminin lorsqu'il désigne une femme.

> C'est un bon professeur.
> C'est une bonne professeur.

Pour *[magistrat](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/magistrat)*, le féminin *[magistrate](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/magistrate)* est communément accepté.

> C'est un bon magistrat.
> C'est une bonne magistrate.

Pour *[chef](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/chef)*, on écrit « une chef » ou de plus en plus « une [cheffe](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cheffe) » au féminin. La prononciation est la même. La forme *[cheffesse](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cheffesse)* existe, mais elle est souvent péjorative de nos jours : souvent ce mot sous-entend qu'une cheffesse n'est pas un vrai chef.

> C'est un bon chef.
> C'est une bonne cheffe.

Pour *[docteur](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/docteur)* en médecine, il existe plusieurs formes féminines mais elles sont rares : une *[docteure](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/docteure)*, une *[doctoresse](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/doctoresse)*, une *[docteur](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/doctrice)*. En revanche, lorsqu'il s'agit de la titulaire d'un doctorat, le féminin (*docteure*, *doctoresse* ou *doctrice*) est devenu fréquent ces dernières années. Même lorsque l'on parle d'une femme, quand on utilise la forme masculine *docteur*, on a tendance à accorder le nom au masculin.

> Cet homme est un bon docteur.
> Cette femme est un bon docteur.   (*Rare :* une bonne docteure, une bonne doctoresse, une bonne doctrice)

Le mot *[médecin](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/m%C3%A9decin)* n'est jamais mis au féminin. La féminisation naturelle serait *[médecine](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/m%C3%A9decine)*, mais ce mot désigne la discipline, jamais une personne.

> Cet homme est un bon médecin.
> Cette femme est un bon médecin.

Comment: C’est très claire, votre réponse. Merci !

Comment: Les [recommandations](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=1&Th_id=358&niveau=) de l'Office Québécois de la Langue Française sont similaires. Pour féminiser une appellation, soit on utilise une variante féminine du mot masculin, soit on utilise un nom épicène (qui n'a qu'une seule forme) parce qu'il se termine déjà par un e comme juge, membre, capitaine.

Answer (score 1):

Il n'est pas correct,à mon avis, d'employer l'article indéfini dans ce cas.

Je dirais :

> Elle est médecin; elle est professeur.

Comment: Oui mais ça ne répond pas à la question. Quand il y a un accord à faire, que fait-on ?

Answer (score 0):

La réponse de None est tout à fait correcte, mais j’ajoute une touche culturelle pour l’usage en France.

Certains substantifs ont une forme féminine bien établie, mais qui désignait autrefois la « femme de ». C’est notamment le cas de *président* (féminin *présidente*) ou *ministre* (mot épicène) : dans l’usage ancien, le président est celui qui préside (une assemblée, une cour de justice, etc.), la présidente est la femme du président (dans le contexte historique de fixation de cet usage, il aurait été impensable qu’une femme accède à une telle fonction, et la « femme de » a vocation à tenir la maison, s’occuper des enfants, etc.). Dans cet usage, il faudra alors maintenir le substantif au masculin, donnant lieu à des constructions étranges. Par exemple, on s’adressait à Édith Cresson comme *madame le premier ministre* ; *madame la première ministre* indiquerait littéralement que son mari est premier ministre, et donc figurativement qu’elle n’est pas compétente et/ou qu’elle doit sa réussite à son mari.

Je pense que cet usage est en voie de disparition. Voici par exemple [un article du Figaro en 2022](https://www.lefigaro.fr/langue-francaise/actu-des-mots/madame-la-premiere-ministre-que-faudra-t-il-dire-si-une-femme-est-nommee-a-la-tete-du-gouvernement-20220516) qui admet l’usage "première ministre" pour Élizabeth Borne. On peut supposer qu’un article paru dans Le Figaro et signé « Maguelonne de Gestas » est plutôt porté sur le conservatisme en matière linguistique.

Indépendemment de l’usage que l’on souhaite adopter à titre personnel, il est évidemment plus courtois de suivre l’avis des intéressées. Ainsi, au tribunal, je m’adresserais initialement à la juge comme *madame la présidente*, mais si celle-ci réclame *madame le président*, je ferai de mon mieux pour accéder à sa demande - si ce n’est par politesse, du moins par prudence ! En sens inverse, [un député a été sanctionné en 2014](https://www.nouvelobs.com/politique/20141007.OBS1370/faut-il-dire-madame-le-president-ou-madame-la-presidente.html) pour avoir insisté sur "madame le président".

Ce conseil de courtoisie vaut également pour les mots où aucune forme féminisée n'est fixée. Ainsi, on pourrait tout à fait imaginer une liste de participants à une conférence scientifique qui incluerait à la fois « madame Dupond, docteur, professeur des universités » et « madame Durand, doctoresse, professeure des universités » : le souhait des intéressées primerait alors sur la cohérence d’ensemble.

Answer (score -3):

Jusqu'à nos jours le point de vue de la [réponse qui précède](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/25029/benita) était le point de vue universel des français, c'est à dire que les noms ne devaient pas prendre de désinence montrant un féminin. La tendance récente est tout le contraire: souvent on trouve « professeur**e** » (que  d'ailleurs l'on ne prononce pas différemment de « professeur ») et le nom est alors un féminin. Similairement, pour « médecin » qu'il est difficile de transformer en « médecin**e** » on trouve le nouveau mot « docteur**e** » alors que l'on a déjà le mot « doctoresse », bien sûr encore un féminin. Pour le genre féminin de chef le mot est « chef**fe** ».

Le point de vue de l'académie a longtemps été que l'on devait considérer qu'un changement de genre n'était pas logique, qu'il n'y avait là qu'une question de *fonction* et que la fonction est la même pour tous et toute -- très sain à mon avis --, mais dernièrement il semble que les académiciens aient changé de conviction et ils* considèreraient que la féminisation des noms de fonction est la voie de l'avenir pour la langue française.

*Ils faudrait quelque chose comme « ils/elles » à la place de « ils » selon la nouvelle façon de penser: ils y a des femmes parmi les académicien.nes (???).