# Is "sage-femme" feminine, even when we don't know whether it refers to a man or a woman?

Tags: genre

Should I write :

> Les sage-femmes sont autorisés à…

or

> Les sage-femmes sont autorisées à…

if these *sage-femmes* can either be men or women?

Comment: [sage-femme](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9S0134)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a trick question. If you don't know if the noun refers to a man or a woman, it should have its default gender: feminine. This noun is used marginally in the masculine for male midwives when you know that the noun refers to a man.

To refer to a group a midwives comprised of women and men, the following sentences would contrast sharply for most native speakers:

- Vingt-et-un sages-femmes se sont assis. (very weird)
- Vingt-et-une sages-femmes se sont assises. (nothing remarkable)

Contrary to popular belief, the masculine is not a neutral gender, it is the default gender for units that can't have a gender such as verbal phrases, small clauses or gender mismatched coordinate nouns. But here, you are looking for a hypernym for a group. In French, for example, a group of cows and bulls is called *vaches* (cows), hens and roosters are *poules* (hens). In both cases, French speakers use the feminine as the hypernym. With humans, the rule of thumb is that the hypernym is generally the masculine form, but it seems that sage-femme is the proverbial exception...

Comment: I wouldn't have thought of the *vaches* and *poules* examples, but that is a compelling argument.

Answer (score 1):

D'après le [TLFi](http://stella.atilf.fr/Dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/visusel.exe?12;s=1955275740;r=1;nat=;sol=3;), une sage-femme est un nom féminin.  Selon le [Robert](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/sage-femme), c'est un nom variable et par hasard sujet de RO de 1990 (sagefemme) :

➙ accoucheur. Des sages-femmes. Un sage-femme. ➙ maïeuticien

[Reverso](https://context.reverso.net/translation/french-english/sage-homme) donne des phrases avec un sage-homme.

Du coup, [L'association nationale des étudiant.e.s. sages-femmes](http://anesf.com/index.php/la-profession/) (leur ponctuation) n'utilise que le pronom *elle* pour remplacer le nom.

Donc pour décrire des hommes et des femmes,

> Conformément à l’article L.4151-1 du code de la santé publique, **les sages-femmes sont autorisées** à concourir aux activités d’assistance médicale à la procréation.  [Ordre des sages-femmes](http://www.ordre-sages-femmes.fr/etre-sage-femme/competences/general/)

---

According to the TLFi, sage-femme is feminine, but Le ROBERT lists it as variable. Also, it was part of the spelling reform of 1990 which (optionally) removed the hyphenation.

[Reverso](https://context.reverso.net/translation/french-english/sage-homme) gives examples of un sage-homme.

L'ANESF, L'association nationale des étudiant.e.s sages-femmes (their punctuation) only uses *elle* as a pronoun for sage-femme, interestingly enough.

If the group is comprised of men and women, the plural would be

> Conformément à l’article L.4151-1 du code de la santé publique, **les sages-femmes sont autorisées** à concourir aux activités d’assistance médicale à la procréation.  [Ordre des sages-femmes](http://www.ordre-sages-femmes.fr/etre-sage-femme/competences/general/)

Comment: You wrote `autorisés` and not `autorisées`, therefore implying that sage-femmes is not feminine in that phrase. That definitely looks odd to me. Was that a verbatim quote from one of your sources?

Comment: @Domino Thank you for pointing this out. I have corrected the error and given another example.  Trop de tafs.