# « Éducatrice » et pas « éducateur » ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, genre, québec

La semaine dernière, j'ai écouté l'épisode du 28 août du balado québécois [« À la une »](https://ici.radio-canada.ca/ohdio/premiere/emissions/nouvelles-info-matin-canada-monde-politique/episodes/803225/rattrapage-lundi-28-aout-2023). Pendant la discussion sur la pénurie de personnel dans les écoles du Québec, j'ai entendu un chroniqueur parler d'un ratio normal de « une éducatrice pour vingt jeunes » vers la 14<sup>e</sup> minute. Étant donné que les instituteurs ne sont pas forcément des femmes, pourquoi dirait-on « éducatrice » et pas « éducateur » ? Je me demande si je n'ai pas compris le contexte.

Comment: I should also know that I was listening to this over my lunch and that "éducatrice" is used a number of times before (and possibly after) as well. At first, I thought I must have misheard or misinterpreted, but I listened to the section again and confirmed that my ears were fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plutôt que de choisir les nommer *éducateurs et éducatrices*, *éducateurs/trices*, voire le difficilement prononçable  *éducateur·rice·s*, le choix a été fait de retenir la forme féminine pour rendre le fait que les femmes sont plus nombreuses que les hommes dans ces métiers<sup>1</sup>.

C'est un ***accord de majorité*** comme existent aussi l'*[accord de proximité](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/49115/inoffensifs-inoffensives/49117#49117)* et l'*[accord au choix](https://www.noslangues-ourlanguages.gc.ca/fr/cles-de-la-redaction/ecriture-inclusive-accords#accord-au-choix)*.

cf. [Manifeste pour que le masculin ne l'emporte plus sur le féminin](https://www.afef.org/manifeste-pour-que-le-masculin-ne-lemporte-plus-sur-le-feminin)

<sup>1</sup> <sub>En 2021, la proportion de femmes parmi les « Enseignants / enseignantes au primaire et préscolaire » était de 87,5% (voir [ici](https://www.quebec.ca/emploi/informer-metier-profession/explorer-metiers-professions/4032-enseignants-enseignantes-au-primaire-et-prescolaire)), et ce pourcentage ne cesse de croître (il était de 84% en 2016). (Commentaire de @Segorian)</sub>

Comment: C'est bien cela. En 2021, la proportion de femmes parmi les « Enseignants / enseignantes au primaire et préscolaire » était de 87,5% (voir [ici](https://www.quebec.ca/emploi/informer-metier-profession/explorer-metiers-professions/4032-enseignants-enseignantes-au-primaire-et-prescolaire)), et ce pourcentage ne cesse de croître (il était de 84% en 2016).

Comment: @Segorian *Le féminin l'emporte sur le masculin* quand il représente la majorité, c'est logique !

Comment: Thanks, I thought it might be something like this but wasn’t sure.

Comment: On retrouve de même assez souvent "infirmière".

Comment: @MasB ainsi que [*sage-femme*](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/42701/is-sage-femme-feminine-even-when-we-dont-know-whether-it-refers-to-a-man-or).